# spark dataframe sqlserver

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to insert records to SQL Server Database using DataFrameWriter using the below in the insert statement:

```
List<MyDataModel> dataRecords = MyProcess.getData(input);
JavaRDD <MyDataModel> dataRecordsRDD = jsc.parallelize(dataRecords);
DataFrame schemaDataRecords = sqlContext.createDataFrame(dataRecordsRDD, MyDataModel.class);
schemaDataRecords.write().mode("append").options(options).jdbc(url, myTable, jdbcConnProperties);
```

Getting the exception table exists while trying to insert records:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: There is already an object named 'MY_TABLE' in the database. at      com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
```

In order to resolve the issue, is there any work around available in Spark 1.4 to write to SQL Server using RDD/ DataFrames? (Without an upgrade to 1.6)

Tried the following snippet using Spark 1.4.

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://myserver;user=myuser;password=mypassword;database=mydb");
boolean tableExists = org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JdbcUtils.tableExists( connection, "MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE");
System.out.println("Table : " + "MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE" + " - exists ? " + tableExists);
```

Output looks like-
Table : MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE - exists ? false

Comment: Did you try using Spark 1.6 api ?